# Blog for existing Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing rails application/website that I want to add a blog to.  I would like to access it by www.existingapplication.com/blog so I was thinking it would need to be some kind of plugin or engine or something.  Does something like this exist?  The main thing is that it can't be a standalone rails application, it has to be an addon to an existing app.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar as well and stumbled upon Rails Engine.
It is a great way to create one.

As for you, just use this:
https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue

Someone already created an app to help add a blog to your site. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use Tumblr or similar, and redirect (or proxy) requests to /blog to it? If you're willing to use blog.application.com, you can even just set up a cname and be done with it. Blogging is a *very* solved problem at this point, and it makes little sense to staple one onto your application at the code level.

Comment: That might work.  Currently hosting at heroku.  Would this still be possible?

Comment: Yeah, certainly. Setting up a cname is done with your DNS management; it'll just alias blog.yourdomain.com to whatever your Tumblr blog is.

Answer (score 0):

If you run it on a subdomain (blog.existingapplication.com/) it is even easier to setup and will definitely be doable through Heroku.